# How do I create a "like" filter view in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Here's an example of what I need in sql:

> SELECT name FROM employ WHERE name LIKE **%bro%**

How do I create view like that in CouchDB?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simple answer is that CouchDB views aren't ideal for this.

The more complicated answer is that this type of query tends to be very inefficient in typical SQL engines too, and so if you grant that there will be tradeoffs with *any* solution then CouchDB actually has the benefit of letting you choose your tradeoff.

1. **The SQL Ways**

When you do `SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE %bro%`, all the SQL engines I'm familiar with must do what's called a "full table scan". This means the server reads every row in the relevant table, and brute force scans the field to see if it matches.

You can do this in CouchDB 2.x with a Mango query using the `$regex` [operator](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/database/find.html#operators). The query would look something like this for the basic case:

```
{"selector":{
  "name": {
    "$regex": "bro"
  }
}}
```

There do not appear to be any options exposed for case-sensitivity, etc. but you could extend it to match only at the beginning/end or more complicated patterns. If you can also restrict your query via some other (indexable) field operator, that would likely help performance. As the documentation warns:

> Regular expressions do not work with indexes, so they should not be used to filter large data sets. […]

You can do a full scan in CouchDB 1.x too, using a [temporary view](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Temporary_Views):

```
POST /some_database/_temp_view

{"map": "function (doc) { if (doc.name && doc.name.indexOf('bro') !== -1) emit(null); }"}
```

This will look through every single document in the database and give you a list of matching documents. You can tweak the map function to also match on a document type, or to emit with a certain key for ordering — `emit(doc.timestamp)` — or some data value useful to your purpose — `emit(null, doc.name)`.

2. **The "tons of disk space available" way**

Depending on your source data size you could create an index that emits every possible "interior string" as its permanent (on-disk) view key. That is to say for a name like "Dobros" you would `emit("dobros"); emit("obros"); emit("bros"); emit("ros"); emit("os"); emit("s");`. Then for a term like '%bro%' you could query your view with `startkey="bro"&endkey="bro\uFFFF"` to get all occurrences of the lookup term. Your index will be approximately the size of your text content *squared*, but if you need to do an arbitrary "find in string" faster than the full DB scan above and have the space this might work. You'd be better served by a data structure designed for [substring searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring_index) though.

Which brings us too...

3. **The Full Text Search way**

You could use a CouchDB plugin ([couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) now via [Dreyfus/Clouseau](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2015/text-search-apache-couchdb/) for 2.x, [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/08/01/couchb-integration.html), [SQLite's FTS](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/couchdb.html)) to generate an auxiliary text-oriented index into your documents.

Note that most full text search indexes [don't naturally support](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F) arbitrary wildcard prefixes either, likely for similar reasons of space efficiency as we saw above. Usually full text search doesn't imply "brute force binary search", but "word search". YMMV though, take a look around at the options available in your full text engine.

If you don't really need to find "bro" *anywhere* in a field, you can implement basic "find a word starting with X" search with regular CouchDB views by just splitting on various locale-specific word separators and omitting these "words" as your view keys. This will be more efficient than above, scaling proportionally to the amount of data indexed.

Comment: for the answer, number 1. actually i'm used bigcouch not couchdb, and bigcouch haven't temporary view... number 2. that's bad idea, because i have a lot of document that have more than 2 word as a key... number 3. i already try it, but i check elasticsearch and couchdb-lucene performance was realy bad (i check it with apache benchmark)

Comment: I think CouchDB 2 has no temporary views. Is there a way to do that with Mango queries?

Comment: @wb9688 Yes, Mango queries include a `$regex` operator which would have similar performance to a temporary view. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, doing searches using `LIKE %...%` aren't really how CouchDB Views work, but you can accomplish a great deal of search capability by installing [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene), it's a fulltext search engine that creates indexes on your database that you can do more sophisticated searches with.

The typical way to "search" a database for a given key, without any 3rd party tools, is to create a view that emits the value you are looking for as the key. In your example:

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.name, doc);
}
```

This outputs a list of all the names in your database.

Now, you would "search" based on the first letters of your key. For example, if you are searching for names that start with "bro".

```
/db/_design/test/_view/names?startkey="bro"&endkey="brp"
```

Notice I took the last letter of the search parameter, and "incremented" the last letter in it. Again, if you want to perform searches, rather than aggregating statistics, you should use a fulltext search engine like lucene. (see above)

Comment: [As suggested by kowsik](http://labs.mudynamics.com/2011/01/21/notes-and-tips-on-optimizing-couchdb-performance/), you should avoid to emit the doc as the value. Do `emit(doc.name, null)` and use `include_docs=true` when querying the view.

Comment: couchdb lucene is a correct answer... but i need a simple code... i want to find a word in sentence... and there is a lot of sentence... simple explain is i want to create **simple search engine**... whitout addon or some thing like **couchdb lucene**... sorry my english is bad..

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions. As per this [table](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/find.html#condition-operators) you can write something like this to return any id that contains "SMS".

```
{
   "selector": {
      "_id": {
         "$regex": "sms"
      }
   }
}
```

Basic regex you can use on that includes

```
"sms$" roughly to LIKE "%sms"
"^sms" roughly to LIKE "sms%"
```

You can read more on regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: Your regex examples are actually switched. `^` matches the beginning of the string, so `^sms` matches a string that starts with `sms`, and so is analogous to `sms%`. `$` matches the end of the string, so `sms$` matches a string that ends with `sms`, and is analogous to `%sms`.

Comment: I just modified it

Answer (score 1):

i found a simple **view code** for my problem...

> {
> "getavailableproduct": 
>        {
>          "map": "function(doc) { 
>            **var prefix = doc['productid'].match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g);**
>            if(prefix) 
>               for(var pre in prefix) { emit(prefix[pre],null); } 
>             }"
>      
>        }
>   
> }

from this view code if i split a key sentence into a key word...
and i can call

> ?key=**"[search_keyword]"**

but i need more complex code because if i run this code i can only find word wich i type (ex: eat, food, etc)...

but if i want to type not a complete word (ex: ea from eat, or foo from food) that code does not work..

Comment: You could use a levenshtein distance algorithm on your returned keys. Whether this is a good idea or not depends on the amount of data you are searching. Example: https://github.com/lysdexia/Lookahead-Lev.

Comment: Pondering it a bit further, I don't think that using my example would be of help since you wish to do arbitrary searches within text, rather than "zeroing in" on mapped values. Lucene is definitely going to be the way to go. You might want to have a look at solr, while you are at it. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but: What about using a "list" function? You can have all your normal views, andthen add a "list" function to the design document to process the view's results:

```js
{
  "_id": "_design/...",
  "views": {
    "employees": "..."
  },
  "lists": {
    "by_name": "..."
  }
}
```

And the function attached to "by_name" function, should be something like:

```js
function (head, req) {
  provides('json', function() {
    var filtered = [];

    while (row = getRow()) {
      // We can retrive all row information from the view
      var key = row.key;
      var value = row.value;
      var doc = req.query.include_docs ? row.doc : {};

      if (value.name.indexOf(req.query.name) == 0) {
        if (req.query.include_docs) {
          filtered.push({ key: key, value: value, doc: doc});
        } else {
          filtered.push({ key: key, value: value});
        }
      }
    }

    return toJSON({ total_rows: filtered.length, rows: filtered });
  });
}
```

You can, of course, use regular expressions too. It's not a perfect solution, but it works to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could emit your documents like normal. `emit(doc.name, null);` I would throw a `toLowerCase()` on that `name` to remove case sensitivity.

and then query the view with a slew of keys to see if something "like" the query shows up.

```
keys = differentVersions("bro"); // returns ["bro", "br", "bo", "ro", "cro", "dro", ..., "zro"]
$.couch("db").view("employeesByName", { keys: keys, success: dealWithIt } )
```

Some considerations

1. Obviously that array can get really big really fast depending on what `differentVersions` returns. You might hit a post data limit at some point or conceivably get slow lookups.
2. The results are only as good as `differentVersions` is at giving you guesses for what the person meant to spell. Obviously this function can be as simple or complex as you like. In this example I tried two strategies, a) removed a letter and pushed that, and b) replaced the letter at position n with all other letters. So if someone had been looking for "bro" but typed in "gro" or "bri" or even "bgro", `differentVersions` would have permuted that to  "bro" at some point.
3. While not ideal, it's still pretty fast since a look up in Couch's b-trees is fast.

Answer (score -1):

why cann't we just use indexOf() in view?

Comment: The view needs to return a more-or-less static list of rows. Those will be sorted by the primary-key returned together with the rows (the first argument to emit). You can query that first parameter by order/startstring/ as can bee seen in other answers. 
But indexOf would by dynamic, as one of its arguments are only available when the query/view is used