# Full Text Search in CouchDB

Tags: java, gwt, full-text-search, couchdb, nosql

I am developing an web application on GWT Framework (JAVA). I am using CouchDB(NoSQL Database)
for storing user profile, user question and answers. I am new in NoSQL Database so i need to implement full text search in my application.

Example : " What is Java ?"

Desired Result :  It could be found all the question which have all three words **What, is, Java** .

So there is any idea how to achieve this result in couchdb.

Comment: Please have a look at below post - [Database Queries the CouchDB Way](http://sitr.us/2009/06/30/database-queries-the-couchdb-way.html) Look at `Search by Keyword` and `Search by Substring` section. - [how do I create a “like” filter view in couchdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509911/how-do-i-create-a-like-filter-view-in-couchdb)

Answer (score 2):

Use [couchdb lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) The integration with couchdb  is straightforward and it would be perfect for your use case. Couch-db lucene supports the entire query syntanx of lucene. For your problem the [+](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html#+) could be used.

> The "+" or required operator requires that the term after the "+" symbol exist somewhere in a the field of a single document.

Here is a sample query

`http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/database/_design/design_name/index_name?q=+"What is java"`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using CouchDB List Functions.

I have a document where I need to search for keywords in name and description field. So, I created a view which will emit doc id as key and doc.name,doc._id,doc.description as value.

Now I created a List function which will use Javascript match function and give me the matching list of doc ids.

Sample Query:
http://localhost:5984/dashboard/_design/testSearch/_list/results/ByName?searchQuery=What is Java

```js
{
  "_id": "_design/testSearch",
  "lists": {
    "results": "function(head, req) { var query= new RegExp(req.query.searchQuery,'i'); var arr=new Array(); var key; var row;  while(row = getRow()) { if(row.value[0].match(query) || row.value[2].match(query))  { arr.push([row.value[0].toUpperCase(),row.value[1]]); key = row.key;}} arr.sort(); send('{\"'+key+'\":\"'+arr+'\"}');}"
  },
  "views": {
    "ByName": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n  if((doc.isdeleted==\"false\" || doc.isdeleted==false) && doc.userid && doc.name){\n    emit(doc._id,[doc.name,doc._id,doc.description]);\n  }\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```