# CouchDB car sale example, possible or not?

Tags: couchdb

I was explaining to a friend of mine how great CouchDB was and I was actually doing a very good job of it, until he asked me if you could do a car sale database. After giving this quite a lot of thought, I have no answer, I kind of think this is impossible.

My dilemma is like this. Lets say a car has an owner_id, manufacturer, year, type, color, milage and price.

My first initial thought was to just emit all the keys. But you might want to search for a car that is blue or red or yellow and is driven between 30.000 and 80.000 miles and with some price range. And given this query, what if you don't search for color ?

The only way I can think of, is doing many queries, and doing a manual brute force diff array in my database layer code. But that seems to be quite excessive, even if there are only a few thousand cars.

So, in short, is this possible to do, in a viable way ?

Comment: Not sure what the tornado tag does here ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB is designed for scalability, and infinite-flexibility ad-hoc queries are not scalable, so therefore it is discouraged. It *is* possible though, with temporary views. You can `POST` your view (query) as a JSON object to `/db/_temp_view`.

See for more details http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Temporary_Views and https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Concept.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286307/487598) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there's no nice way to spell this in CouchDB, in the same way as you might do this in a relational database with support for spatial indices;  That's not to say that there's no hope at all.  You could, for instance, do some simple clustering to index cars that meet a certain set of attributes together.

Mileage and price look like good candidates for this approach.  Most queries will probably specify these values to a single digit

```
function oneDigit(value) {
    var strValue = String(value);
    return (Number(strValue[0]) * Math.pow(10, strValue.length - 1);
}
```

With this, we can build a view which organizes cars into bins based on their price and mileage.

```
function (doc) {
    emit([[oneDigit(doc.mileage), oneDigit(doc.price)], null]);
}
```

It's then a simple matter of getting *all* of the cars that have that feature:

```
for mileage in range(60000, 100000, 10000):
    cars.append(db.view('cars/mileageAndPrice', startkey=[mileage, minPrice], endkey=[mileage + 10000, maxPrice]))
```